# Extjs 4 Grid findcolumn

Tags: extjs4

I search a way in extjs 4 to find grid columns dynamic, because i wrote a function to show errors in editor grid. In version 3 i've made it over

`getColumnModel().findColumnIndex(cellname);`

but column model no longer exists, does anybody has an idea?

Regards

Comment: Please show some of your code.

Answer (score 7):

I just had to work this out, @VoidMan was close. Need to specify the view though. For example:

If your column is configured with an itemId like this:

```
{
header: 'A Column',
dataIndex: 'data',
width: 70,
itemId: 'myColumnItemId'
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
grid.getView().getHeaderCt().child('#myColumnItemId')
```

Comment: +1. thanks for this. in my case, i have use this to disable my `checkcolumn` if current state is in view (CRUD). `grid.getView().getHeaderCt().child('checkcolumn').setDisabled(true);`

Comment: In ExtJs 4.2.1 the above code didn't work. I needed to change it to `grid.getView().headerCt.child('#myColumnItemId')` (headerCt is a property, not a method).

Answer (score 1):

This is something among these lines:

```
myGrid.headerCt.child('#column')
```

where #column its your column itemId. Note, use itemId and not id because columns are now Component and Component id must be unique across all your application.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Ext.grid.header.Container and Ext.view.Table.headerCt